# Error while compiling \align*

Tags: align

I have written the following code :

```
\section{Quantum Harmonic Oscillator}
 The quantum harmonic oscillator is the analogue of harmonic oscillator in classical mechanics scaled down to the quantum domain.
\subsection{One Dimensional Harmonic Oscillator}
\large{Hamiltonian and Eigenstates}
The Hamiltonian of the particle is : 

\begin{align*}
 \hat{H} $= \frac{hat{p^{2}}}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}mw^{2}\hat{x^{2}} \\
a $= b 
\end{align*}
```

On compiling I get the error "File ended while scanning use of \align*."
How do I correct this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need `$` inside align*? it is already math mode. Try `&` instead

Comment: Instead `$` should be `&`

Comment: Not the issue, but: `\large{Hamiltonian and Eigenstates}` is wrong. The text after it will also be large! You probably want something like `\paragraph{…}` or KOMA-Script's `\minisec{…}`.

Comment: As others have said, it is `&` that is used as an alignment character, not `$`. Note also that you don't want that empty line before the `align*` environment, that may give you unwanted vertical space.

Comment: Thank you @Nasser Zarko Torborn. The error was corrected by using &. Clemens,Thank you. I used \subsubsection instead since I wanted a heading.

Comment: `\paragraph` is (despite the name) a macro to create a heading, just like `\subsubsection`. In order, `\part`, `\chapter` (not found in `article`), `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, `\subparagraph`. This is for the standard classes, other classes may use a different set.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.